# Build xlnt library on Windows x64

Tags: c++, windows, build, cmake

I try build xlnt library from rep

> https://github.com/tfussell/xlnt on Windows x64 using cmake:
>   cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles"

and get errors:

> CMake Error at cmake/xlnt.cmake:70 (add_library):
>   Cannot find source file:
>
> ../third-party/miniz/miniz.c
>
> Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp
>    .hxx .in .txx
>   Call Stack (most recent call first):
>    CMakeLists.txt:74 (include)
>
> CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: xlnt.shared
>   CMake Error: Cannot determine link language for target "xlnt.shared".

I am beginner in cmanke, but in directory nessessry file containts:

> xlnt\third-party\miniz.c

What can I do for desition this building problem? 
Thanks for answer

Issue on github: https://github.com/tfussell/xlnt/issues/57

Answer (score 4):

I sucessfly compile the library:

TODO:

1. Edit "cmake/xlnt.cmake": change path form../ to./

> SET(MINIZ ./third-party/miniz/miniz.c ./third-party/miniz/miniz.h)
>
> SET(PUGIXML  ./third-party/pugixml/src/pugixml.hpp ./third-party/pugixml/src/pugixml.cpp ./third-party/pugixml/src/pugiconfig.hpp)

I think that is path-bug. I issued in project about it.

2. `cmake -G "NMake Makefiles"` - `.configure` for VS compiler
3. `nmake` - compile by VS compiler

Comment: Hi f4x. You're the first person to ask a question related to my library, so congrats! I'll be looking into your problem and commenting on the GitHub issue (https://github.com/tfussell/xlnt/issues/57). Good detective work so far.